# Android: ListView Manipulation

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I am using the code below to populate my listview, but I wanted to use another code that displays animation. I am really struggling to see how can I do manipulation and come up merging the codes below. The main issue for me is that I am using `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>` in storing my data, while the other code uses `ArrayList<String>`. Your help will be greatly appreciated and would lead me to further understand BaseAdapters with Hashmap.

I am using the code below:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Hashmap for ListView
            productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            //bMain = (Button) findViewById(R.id.main);

            // Loading products in Background Thread
            new LoadAllProducts().execute();

            // Get listview
            ListView lv = getListView();

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
/**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        //Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);



                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);


                    String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);


                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    productsList.add(map);
                }
            } else {

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } 

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    MainActivity.this, productsList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                TAG_NAME},
                        new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                //updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);

            }
}
```

I am struggling right now now how I can use the code below that enables animation:

**AlphaInActivity**

```
public class AlphaInActivity extends MyListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

BaseAdapter mAdapter = createListAdapter();

AlphaInAnimationAdapter aplhaInAnimationAdapter = new AlphaInAnimationAdapter(mAdapter);
aplhaInAnimationAdapter.setAbsListView(getListView());

getListView().setAdapter(aplhaInAnimationAdapter);

}
}
```

**MyListActivity**

```
public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity {
    private static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getListView().setDivider(null);
}

protected ArrayAdapter<String> createListAdapter() {
    return new MyListAdapter(this, getItems());
}

public static ArrayList<String> getItems() {
    ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        items.add(String.valueOf(i));
}
    return items;
}

private static class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private Context mContext;

    public MyListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> items) {
    super(items);
    mContext = context;


    }

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return getItem(position).hashCode();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView tv = (TextView) convertView;
    if (tv == null) {
        tv = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
    }
    tv.setText("This is row number " + getItem(position));
    return tv;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help, from Google I/O:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=ihzZrS69i_s#t=540s

Comment: Thanks for the video, just a question, is this possible to combine?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You're also asking before you can possibly have finished watching. It might give you some clues to solve this yourself.

Comment: i just want to populate the listview with a different approach like the code below, but I can't see where I can start. I am watching the video. Thanks